# How can a new corresponding author upload a manuscript using the same portal?

Tags: publications, authorship, ieee

I submitted an article to IEEE access and during all the process I was the corresponding author. The paper was finally accepted, but in order to secure funding for the APC I need to make my professor the corresponding author. However, the journal coordinators told me that if I am to change the corresponding author, then the final files will also need to be uploaded by the new corresponding author.

I am using my login details and the manuscript appears in my login spac,e how is my professor going to upload the manuscript? Even if i share my login details with my Professor how is it going to make a difference?

Comment: I am guessing the professor would need t create their own account and upload through there? As a corresponding author you have to provide an email adress for the professor to IEEE, so they probably expect an account with this very email adress to upload the files?